# Upload multiple Images but store in Database only one image

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

How to upload multiple images?

I want to upload multiple images into the database; I select the multiple images and then hit the upload button, but it inserts only one image. Can any expert tell me where I am going wrong?

`Image` class:

```
public partial class Image  
{  
        public int imgID { get; set; }  
        public string ImgPath { get; set; }  
        public long ProdID { get; set; }  

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }  
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddNewProducts(ProductViewModel prod, List file)  
{  
           try  
           {  
               List PTlist = _IproductType.PTList();  
               ViewBag.Ptlist = new SelectList(PTlist, "PType_ID", "P_Name");  

               // Product Color List  
               List pColorList = _IProductColor.PColorlist();  
               ViewBag.pColor_List = new SelectList(pColorList, "C_ID", "C_Name_OR_Code");  

               List pSizeList = _ISize.pSizeList();  
               ViewBag.pSizeLists = new SelectList(pSizeList, "S_ID", "S_Size");  
               string PathDB = string.Empty;  
               Image img = new Image();  

               foreach (HttpPostedFileBase files in file)  
               {  
                   string filename = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);  
                   string _filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssff") + filename;  
                   string extension = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName);  
                   string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/"), _filename);  
                   PathDB = "~/Upload/" + _filename;  

                   if (extension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || extension.ToLower() == ".png")  
                   {  
                       if (files.ContentLength <= 1000000)  
                       {  
                           img = new Image();  
                           img.imgID = prod.ImgID;  
                           img.ImgPath = PathDB;  
                           img.ProdID = prod.ProductID;  
                       }  
                       else  
                           ViewBag.sizemsg = "Size limit exceeded";  
                   }  
                   else  
                       ViewBag.fileformat = "File is not the correct format";  
               } 
        }
}
```

Comment: The requirements are contracditing: "I want to upload multiple images in the database base" and "but insert in the database only 1 image". If you upload the images, you have to store them *someplace* to hand them out during any further request (including he reply). It is also abysmal design to transfer a lot of images across the Internet, to then only actually **use** one of them. Why can the user not simply select the 1 that maters? Why do you need to multiply the amount of bulk data transfer by a high factor?

Comment: Christopher i want to store 1 and multiple images , for example i have a ecommerce website and one product have the multiple images so i want to insert multiple image that's the reason i want to store multiple images.

Comment: You title says your goal is "Upload multiple Images but store in Database only one image". There is no indication that this is your *problem*. So it sounds clearly like a goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you referenced the MCV pattern and used terms like "upload", I am going to asume this is Web Development. I am also asuming your pattern is:

- user uploads a bunch of images
- you do some processing on the images
- you present the processed images, so the user can select one
- that one is actually persisted

**The "reconsider this path" answer**

If you do, that is definitely a bad approach. Transfering bulk data to only actually use a fraction of it? A very common beginners mistake with Web and Database Development. Putting a lot of CPU work on the Server side is another one.

Whatever processing you are doing, you should ideally be doing it on the client side: Browser Plugin. Custom Client Side applicaiton. JavaScript element. Even just demanding a specific format from the user. That sort of thing. And then only upload that specific image.

If the server never has to see a bit from those images you do not want, it is a good design.

**Staging table/database**

This is the asnwer you are really comited to your approach or it is not a option for some reason. In order to have the server process and display a image, it **must** be saved on the server side.

In memory is not really an option. With a massively paralell design and ThreadPools of 50-100 Threads per CPU core, WebServers are notoriously easy to run [out of resources, particular memory](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020006/how-to-troubleshoot-out-of-memory-issues-system-outofmemoryexception-i). And that asumes you can actually persist something in memory like that to begin with (the design does not make that easy, to get you off that path).

So the next best bet would be a staging table or temp directory. Something where you can:

- store the images you just uploaded
- have some background process process them
- you can hand the processed images out of
- you can transfer the one image the user wants into the proper persistent database
- something that is regualry clearing up any data the user never made a decision on

Personally I would advise for a seperate set of DB Tables. In our day, temp direcotiries are a security vulnerability that no admin should accept without looking for alternatives.

Comment: sir thanks for the details answer. sir my problem is if I select the image only one then I don't have the problem with this code.  if I select the 2 images or more then 2 images are also stored in the upload folder but the path of the two images is not stored in a database only 1 image path stored.  so can you tell me where i am wrong . @Christopher

Comment: @thegovtjobs The question then is: In wich line are you storing both folders? Are you just storing one folder? One folder two times? Overwrite the first folder with the second folder? I see nothing that looks even remotely like a SQL query. So it is impossible to say. | As for general options of storing BLOBs in/with a Database, I like to give this intro into filestream as a overview of the options: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/